# How to disable zoom on window phone 8

Tags: html, css, windows-phone-8, zooming

i have a simple page which can be zoomed over the window phone, however i want to lock the zoom. any help how can i prevent webpage from zoom over window phone 8

here is the code

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>HI there</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js" ></script>


</head>



<body>
    <div style="width:100%; height:100px; background:red;">
        hi this is just the sample
    </div>
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<head>

    <title>HI there</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js" ></script>
<!-- add the viewport tag -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
    <style>
/* not needed      @-ms-viewport{
    width: device-width;
                   } */
    </style>


</head>
```

add `initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,` to the viewport tag in the head

Comment: hi, thanks , one query please i dont have window phone right now , can i check the same in desktop ie10 after changing the user agent from tools-->changeuseragentstring---> ie for windowphone8..  does it works same ..does the zoom have locked over this browser()

Comment: have you a windows phone?

Comment: he he he... ok no probs... does this meta tag works for all mobile device like android and iphone. actually  i hve iphone and android phone now..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52046/discussion-between-jatt-net-and-omegaiori)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding  `maximum-scale=1` to that meta tag? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag for more info.